# Git reset status after undo changes

Tags: git, version-control

I am new to Git so I am not sure how to fix my current situation.

I have a "master" repository `A`. I then have a clone of it as repository `B`. Both happen to be on the same machine, although in the future they will not be. `A` is a remote for `B`.

My design for this is that changes will be made to `A`, and `B` will simply pull from upstream to update. `B` may have some local changes sometimes.

The issue is that I accidentally made a change on `B` instead of `A`. Before this change, both repos were identical. The change was a revert some images from a previous commit (taking them from "original" state to the "correct" state), but I don't think the fact that it was a revert matters. Then, noticing that I did it on the wrong repo, I undid *what I just reverted* (setting the images to original state before I started) and instead made the change on the "master"/upstream `A`.

[image]

Now, `B` has the original images again, and `A` has the newly fixed images. The problem is that `B` says that it is two revisions ahead of `A`. It offers me an option to push to `A`, but errors if I do:

> remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch:
>   refs/heads/master         remote: error: By default, updating the
>   current branch in a non-bare repository         remote: error: is
>   denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
>   remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset
>   --hard' to match         remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
>
> remote: error:          remote: error: You can set
>   'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to         remote:
>   error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing
>   into         remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not
>   recommended unless you         remote: error: arranged to update its
>   work tree to match what you pushed in some         remote: error:
>   other way.         remote: error:          remote: error: To squelch
>   this message and still keep the default behaviour, set         remote:
>   error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
>   To C:\dev\jenkins-1.501  ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch
>   is currently checked out)

**How do I get `B` to not being "ahead" of `A`?** I now have `A` as it is supposed to be, and I want to simply pull the changes into `B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of "pulling the changes into" `B` (which means "adding new stuff"), you need to make `B`'s `master` branch-label point back to the same commit that `A` says.

Since you are sure you want to get rid of all changes made on `B`, this is easy!

Step 1, get up-to-date (a no-op if you are already up to date):

```
B$ git fetch origin
```

Step 2, make absolutely sure you're on machine `B` and are on branch `master`, etc.

```
B$ hostname; git status # etc
```

Step 3: on `B`, say that the branch you're on now (i.e., `master`) should be set to the same point as `origin/master`, i.e., "the `master` I saw on `A` the last time I did a `fetch` to get up to date":

```
B$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

(Incidentally, all of this is command-line; any GUI you have running, you may have to force it to re-read the underlying git repo to pick up the changes.)

Comment: The thing is there are *other* working copy changes on `B` as well.

Comment: Working copy changes that you want to keep?  You said in the original question that you wanted to discard those changes.

Comment: No, there is nothing about that in my question. I did re-did the local changes after using this method however.

Comment: Ah, if there are changes you want to save, you can do that, but it's more work.  But I guess at this point it's not a problem anymore :-)